# Python script that uses selenium to switch from local environment to remote based on the environment it is run in

Tags: python, git, selenium, pytest

I have a suite of tests that utilize the selenium webdriver for firefox. I have scripts that I've written that I'd like to check the current environment it's being run in to switch between localhost and a remote server. What's the best way to accomplish this?

```
    def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
                                   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX) #remote-server or localhost
```

I am using a windows environment to test locally in, while the remote server is linux. Is their a system variable I can check against that can perform a swap of:

http://**localhost**:4444/wd/hub to http://**remote-server**:4444/wd/hub

This would improve my workflow allowing me to not worry about switching this variable out every time I commit to and from source control. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, for example, you could check the hostname of your server and change the url according:

```
import socket
server_hostname = 'MyServer'

if socket.gethostname() == server_hostname:
    #Remote environment
else:
    #Local environment
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not only me working on this. However, if the remote host name doesn't change, I could use similar logic to get it to check against the remote host name, and if it isn't that then I can default to localhost. Sound about right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It makes much more sense to use the server hostname. I updated the answer and fixed a typo too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to have a system environment variable that you can point to the remote server by default, but if it's defined, then you could point to an alternate server (e.g. localhost).

So, on your local environment define a system environment variable "MY_SERVER_HOST", then in your code use:

```
my_server_host = os.getenv("MY_SERVER_HOST", "remote-server")
```

when run in any environment that doesn't have the env set, it'll use that remote-server.

This allows you to override that anywhere.

PS: if you have a properties file somewhere, that would be a great place to store the default value of the remote-server.

PPS: if you might have multiple possible remote servers, you could flip this approach and default to localhost, then use the env var on any other machine to specify the target host.